# (T-SQL)Rise or Fall In Growth

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to get the Rise or Fall in Growth on the number of orders placed (created) this month compared to the prior month.

It should look like this:
[image]

```
SELECT [o].ClientID
    ,[ru].UnitName
    ,YEAR(GETDATE()) AS [Current Year]
    ,[Current Month] = 
        CASE 
            WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1 THEN 'JANUARY'
            WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 2 THEN 'FEBRUARY'
            WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 3 THEN 'MARCH'
            WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 4 THEN 'APRIL'
            WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 5 THEN 'MAY'
            WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 6 THEN 'JUNE'
            WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 7 THEN 'JULY'
            WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 8 THEN 'AUGUST'
            WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 9 THEN 'SEPTEMBER'
            WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 10 THEN 'OCTOBER'
            WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 11 THEN 'NOVEMBER'
            WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12 THEN 'DECEMBER'
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ,COUNT([o].OrderID) AS [Current Month Orders Placed]
    ,[Prior Month] = 
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, - 1, getdate())) = 1 THEN 'JANUARY'
            WHEN DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, - 1, getdate())) = 2 THEN 'FEBRUARY'
            WHEN DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, - 1, getdate())) = 3 THEN 'MARCH'
            WHEN DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, - 1, getdate())) = 4 THEN 'APRIL'
            WHEN DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, - 1, getdate())) = 5 THEN 'MAY'
            WHEN DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, - 1, getdate())) = 6 THEN 'JUNE'
            WHEN DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, - 1, getdate())) = 7 THEN 'JULY'
            WHEN DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, - 1, getdate())) = 8 THEN 'AUGUST'
            WHEN DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, - 1, getdate())) = 9 THEN 'SEPTEMBER'
            WHEN DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, - 1, getdate())) = 10 THEN 'OCTOBER'
            WHEN DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, - 1, getdate())) = 11 THEN 'NOVEMBER'
            WHEN DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, - 1, getdate())) = 12 THEN 'DECEMBER'
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ,COUNT([o].OrderID) AS [Prior Months Orders Placed]
    ,[Current Month Orders Placed] * [ Prior Months Orders Placed] AS [Comparison Percentage]
FROM Valuations.dbo.[Order] [o](NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN Valuations.dbo.resnet_unit ru(NOLOCK) ON [o].ClientID = ru.UnitId
WHERE YEAR([o].DateCreated) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    AND MONTH([o].DateCreated) = MONTH(GETDATE())
GROUP BY MONTH([o].DateCreated)
    ,[o].ClientID
    ,[ru].UnitName
```

Comment: sql server version 2008 or 2012?

Comment: Do yourself a favor a try     Select DateName(MM,GetDate())

Comment: server version is 2008.

Comment: where would I placed Select DateName(MM,GetDate())

Comment: You could eliminate the MONTH case statement.  Try the following  instead  ,[Current Month] = DateName(MM,GETDATE())    ,[Prior Month] = DateName(MM,DateAdd(MM,-1,GetDate()))

Comment: I would consider dropping those NOLOCK hints unless you are ok with data that at best is mostly accurate most of the time. That hint can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ If you are going to stick with using query hints the WITH keyword being omitted has been deprecated. Another suggestion, when using dateadd and datename functions it is best to avoid the shortcuts because they are vague. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: The Select DateName(MM,GetDate() Works. But how do I get both columns in the same query to display prior months, current Month ,Percentage?

Comment: Your two columns PriorMonthsOrdersPlaced and CurrentMonthOrdersPlaced are the exact same value  Count(o.OrderID) so this isn't going to work. You have also filtered out any rows from the previous month with your where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need it to, untested obviously as you have provided no test data.

```
SELECT [o].ClientID
    ,[ru].UnitName
    ,YEAR(GETDATE()) AS [Current Year]

    ,[Current Month] = dateName(MM,GetDate())
    ,sum(case when [o].DateCreated >= dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,getdate()),0)  -- First day of this month
                    and [o].DateCreated < dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,getdate())+1,0) -- First day of next month
                then 1
                else 0
                end) AS [Current Month Orders Placed]

    ,[Prior Month] = dateName(MM,dateadd(MM,-1,GetDate()))
    ,sum(case when [o].DateCreated >= dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,getdate())-1,0)    -- First day of last month
                    and [o].DateCreated < dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,getdate()),0) -- First day of this month
                then 1
                else 0
                end) AS [Prior Months Orders Placed]

    --Current Month Orders Placed
    ,isnull(sum(case when [o].DateCreated >= dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,getdate()),0)   -- First day of this month
                    and [o].DateCreated < dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,getdate())+1,0) -- First day of next month
                then 1.  -- Decimal points ensure the percentage division works by not returning integer values.
                else 0.
                end)
         --Prior Months Orders Placed
        / nullif(sum(case when [o].DateCreated >= dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,getdate())-1,0)    -- First day of last month
                        and [o].DateCreated < dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,getdate()),0) -- First day of this month
                    then 1.
                    else 0.
                    end),0),0) AS [Comparison Percentage]

FROM Valuations.dbo.[Order] [o](NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN Valuations.dbo.resnet_unit ru(NOLOCK) ON [o].ClientID = ru.UnitId

WHERE [o].DateCreated >= dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,getdate())-1,0) -- First day of last month
    and [o].DateCreated < dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,getdate())+1,0) -- First day of next month

GROUP BY [o].ClientID
        ,[ru].UnitName
```

Comment: @DariusCastillo Try now.

Comment: This is perfect. So, how do I add the percentage (%) sign to the Comparison Percentage?

Comment: Format the data in your presentation layer...  If you really want the SQL to output a formatted string (not recommended) you would need to multiply by 100, convert to `nvarchar` and then add a `%` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

If `DateCreated` datatype is not `date`, change the `convert(...)` datatype to match.

Using [**`with common_table_expression as ()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** to get data for the last and current month and compare them:

```
with cte as (
  select 
        o.ClientId
      , ClientName  = ru.UnitName
      , [Year]      = datepart(year,o.CreatedDate)
      , [Month]     = datename(month,o.CreatedDate)
      , [OrderCount]= count(o.OrderId)
      , rn          = row_number() over (
          partition o.ClientId, ru.UnitName
          order by datepart(year,o.CreatedDate),datename(month,o.CreatedDate)
        )
    from Valuations.dbo.Order o(nolock)
        inner join Valuations.dbo.resnet_unit ru(nolock) on o.ClientId = ru.UnitId
    where o.DateCreated >= /* First day of last month */
      convert(date,dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-1, 0))
    group by 
        o.ClientId
      , o.ClientName
      , ru.UnitName
      , datepart(year,o.CreatedDate)
      , datename(month,o.CreatedDate)
)
select 
    c.ClientId
  , c.ClientName
  , c.[Year]
  , c.[Month]
  , [Orders Placed] = c.OrderCount
  , [Prior Month] = p.[Month]
  , [Prior Month Count]
  , [Comparison Percentage] = c.OrderCount / (nullif(p.OrderCount ,0)+0.0)
from (select * from cte where rn = 1) as c
  left join (select * from cte where rn = 2) as p
    on c.ClientId = p.ClientId
```